# obtain verified paypal email Id of merchant

Tags: iphone, ios, email, paypal, verify

I have integrated paypal with my ios application and  wants my transaction to complete only if merchant has a verified paypal email id. Please help me to solve this problem . Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A Get Verified Status API provided by Paypal Adaptive Accounts.
On PHP you should have to integrate SDK "adaptiveaccounts-sdk-php-namespace-php" then using API call you can verified Paypal ID.

Answer (score 0):

I suugest you use this parameter: `payer_status=verified` for IPN or `PayerStatus= Verified` for Express Checkout. According to PayPal this means the following:

> The payer’s PayPal account status. A value of Verified means that the
>   customer has confirmed ownership of a bank account or has verified his
>   account status through other means.

Comment: ,I am thankful for your response,but I want receipent's paypal email address should be verified before transaction takes place for the convinence of customers.

Comment: PayPal's addresses are always verified because they are the main information they hold about customers. Their whole business is set around email. You can always consider email addresses coming from them as verified.

Comment: I think you are not getting my point sir,in my application when merchant sign in ,he has to select payment option through which he want to receive payment,if he selects paypal ,then I have to redirect him to paypal site and he their enters his paypal email id and password, here I want a response in form of dictionary where I can fetch user's email address and store in my applications database.

Comment: Sorry but you are right. I didn't get your point. Unfortunately, I don't know how you can verify the email address of a merchant. Perhaps there is no way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

After lot of search,I found my answer ,there is "GetVerifiedStatus" api provided by paypal which is used to check whether user is having correct paypal email address .I have solved it using the link below:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/getverifiedstatus-api-operation